# Sharepoint JSLink Sharepoint Hosted app

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin, jsom, jslink

I have a List with a column exam type in it. I need to use JSLink so that I can format the List using datatables.

I created a custom page called Exam.aspx and added the web part to the page but can't find a way to add the JSLINK.

The sole purpose is to format the list using datables.

Can you point me to an example to format the list using datables?

```
 <WebPartPages:XsltListViewWebPart ID"ListViewWebPart" runat="server"
             "Lists/Exam">
            </WebPartPages:XsltListViewWebPart>`
```